# Loop through column values in Temp Table with N columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a scenario inside a stored procedure where a temporary table will be generated with an unknown number of columns (`Column1.....ColumnN`). One of the columns will be the total\sum of few of the other columns.
The clients requirement is to show the percentage value of each column in comparison to the total column

`(C1*100)/Total as P1 ,(C2*100)/Total as P2.....`

I have really been unable to find a solution to this problem other than doing it in the front end using LINQ. I am wondering if there is any way to achieve this in SQL as that would give me performance benefits.The last thing I want to do is to loop through the rows and columns in C# which will hammer the server.

Comment: How to identify the Sum column among all the columns?

Comment: The Name of the Sum column is known or Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @cols    AS NVARCHAR(max),
        @calCols AS NVARCHAR(max),
        @query   AS NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT *
INTO   #temptable
FROM   (SELECT journeyid,
               notchl,
               Cast(Sum(Datediff(second, starttime, endtime)) AS FLOAT) AS
               Duration
        FROM   (SELECT notchlog.*,
                       CASE
                         WHEN ( Isnumeric(notch) = 1
                                AND notch < 0 ) THEN 'DYN'
                         WHEN notch = 'I' THEN 'IDLE'
                         WHEN notch = 'C' THEN 'COASTING'
                         ELSE 'N' + notch
                       END AS NotchL
                FROM   notchlog)Sub1
        GROUP  BY journeyid,
                  notchl)SUB1

SELECT @cols = Stuff(( SELECT ',' + Quotename(notchl)
                       FROM   #temptable
                       GROUP  BY notchl
                      --order by value
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE                       
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                     , 1, 1, '')

SELECT @calCols = Stuff((SELECT ',' + 'ROUND(' + Quotename(notchl)
                                + '*100/RunningTime,2)  as '
                                + Quotename(notchl)
                         FROM   #temptable
                         GROUP  BY notchl
                        --order by value
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                        , 1, 1, '')

SET @query =N'Select * INTO #ResultTable FROM( SELECT Journeyid, '
            + @cols + ' from               (                 select Journeyid, NotchL, Duration                 from #TempTable Group By JourneyId,NotchL,Duration             ) x              pivot              (                 max(x.duration)                 for NotchL in ('
            + @cols
            + ')             ) p ) Sub2                                                            select NL.JourneyId,RunningTime,'
            + @calCols
            + N' from #ResultTable R INNER Join (Select JourneyID,Sum(DateDiff(second,starttime,endtime))             as RunningTime FROM NotchLog Group By JourneyID)NL  ON NL.JourneyID=R.JourneyId             INNER Join Journeys J ON J.JourneysID=R.JourneyID                                       Drop Table #ResultTable '

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @query;

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: good dear, but I got the error at for xml. It is something you missing?

Comment: This script is dependent on the Database I am running on.

Answer (score 1):

I had done, I just change according to you and you can read the comment for better understand. I feel the schemaname is dbo, else change it.

```
-------------1. first step --------------
--create table for exercise
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [isTrue] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--insert date
insert into tblTest values(1,'true'),(2,'false'),(3,'false'),(4,'true'),(5,'false')
select * from tbltest

-------------2. second step --------------
--now start to get column name one by one
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = '[dbo].[tblTest]', 
@SearchStr nvarchar(128)='id', @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110) --this is used to get only particular column result, to check remove uncomment in cursor
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

DECLARE @Columnname varchar(100) ,@ColumnIndex int --, @PurchaseQty int -- declare temp variable which you u
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630), ColIndex int)

DECLARE getItemID CURSOR    
        FOR     
        select column_name, ordinal_position from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)

    OPEN getItemID
        FETCH NEXT  FROM getItemID INTO @Columnname, @ColumnIndex 
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                    --select @Columnname, @ColumnIndex ;
                     INSERT INTO #Results
                        EXEC
                        (
                            'SELECT ''' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) , '+ @ColumnIndex +'
                            FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' 
                            --remove this to get only particular column entry
                            --+' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2 
                        )
                   FETCH NEXT   FROM getItemID INTO @Columnname, @ColumnIndex 
                END

CLOSE getItemID

DEALLOCATE getItemID

select * from #Results 

drop table #Results
```

Comment: Thank you. I adopted a different technique. Anyway for Temp tables Information_Schema won't work. We need..
select name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#resulttable'');

Comment: Thanks to help you. good to give your response for other, if you solved.